# Primeng turbo table paging all selection

Tags: angular, primeng

My customer has asked that I add an option to a grid we are using the turbo table for to show all rows on a single page. I cannot find any way that this is built into the library. Does anybody know how to do this? It seams like too common a need for it to not be in there. I could count the records and set the total count within the rowsPerPageOptions, but that sounds like way more of a hack than what should be there and would easily confuse my user base unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize `rows` property with the length of the data array where you have the data.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-turbo-table-gakxxv?file=app/provider-search/provider-search.component.html)

**HTML:**

```
<p-table [columns]="cols" [value]="myData" [paginator]="true" [rows]="myData.length">
   ....
</p-table>
```

**TS:**

```
export class ComponentClass{
    myData: any = [];  // data for the table
}
```

Also refer to the documentation, **Properties** section: [PrimeNG Turbo Table](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table)

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your answer as I unfortunately cannot access your stackblitz from my network, but I believe setting the rows property will just show that many rows won't it? What I am wanting is to have a choice of ALL within the RowsPerPage drop down. I truly hope that nobody ever hits it as there is no reason to show that many rows on one page (I am providing options up to 100 already), but I have been asked to make it work.